# Not able to receive file at Http producer(tomcat server)

Tags: java, apache-camel

1. I am starting now with Camel. I am trying to create route as to process file from a file component and pass on to a http tomcat server.
2. I have created the route as follows

**from("file:inbox?noop=false").to("http://localhost:8080/myServer/");**

I have also tried using my I.P address in place of localhost

1. I am not getting any compilation error nor at runtime and the file is getting processed from inbox folder, but I am not able to receive the file in myServer directory.
2. Camel version I am using is 2.0.0 .

Comment: Are you sure you have something listening on port 8080 that accepts input at the `/myServer` URL?

Comment: Yes my tomcat server is running in the same port and I am bale to deploy myServer application in the server.

Actually my requirement is that, I need to create an http producer which can send file to an http server using apache-camel.

Comment: Do you see any requests to /myServer in the access logs? What protocol is the file being sent with this type of route?

Comment: I have checked the catalina.log and localhost.log files in my tomcat home directory and there no any request to /myServer. 
Camel container creates a route between file consumer to http producer and picks up the files from file consumer and uploads to the http server.

Comment: Are you really using Camel 2.0.0, this is an old release?

Comment: What application have you deployed in Apache Tomcat, that listen on /myServer? I assume you want some application that listen and accepts multipart POSTs (eg files) and possible write that to a file directory

Comment: Can you upload a file from the command line or some other tool (eg without using Camel) and does that work?

Comment: I am using Camel 2.0.0 version. Yes Claus, I need an application that listen and accepts multipart POSTs (eg files) and possible write that to a file directory.
Do I need to implement logic in myServer application to read the files from the POST request body and write the files to the directory, or is that HTTP component works like a FTP component, which writes the files to a directory.

Answer (score 0):

yep, this should work...you should use the latest version of Camel though [(2.8.2](http://camel.apache.org/camel-282-release.html) currently)...here is a simple unit test to show the FILE->HTTP in action...

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class FileToHttpRouterTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=200")
                    .setBody(simple("${exchangeId}"))
                    .to("file://tmp/inbox");

                from("file://tmp/inbox")
                    .to("http://localhost:9000/myTest");

                from("jetty:http://localhost:9000/myTest")
                    .log("received: ${body}");
            };
        };
    }
}
```